# Ubuntu-desktop not running on boot

Tags: gui, surface

I am sorry that the info will be vague at the start. But I don't know what to give, so sorry for that.

I started my laptop and now it is not booting into the GUI. I can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, the terminal opens and everything seems to function normally.

I am running a 'custom' kernel from surface-linux and Ubuntu 20.04.

I saw something that a job was running for `ipts/0`.

It would be awesome if I can get some instructions to give you some more info.

Things tried:

- Reinstalling ubuntu-desktop

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running? "Ubuntu 20" isn't really (usually) a suitable answer. Is it 20.04 or 20.10? Seeing as you can get into the terminal, have you tried reinstalling the desktop? `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the feedback. It's 20.04, I have tried reinstalling ubuntu-desktop without luck.

Comment: You should [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1312549/edit) your post to update it with the proper version so that others may be able to help you.

Comment: Thank you, added the info!